# javascript convert object to string

Tags: javascript, string, object, eval

I have some form with several values depending which is selected

```
<form action="#">
    <select id="tropa1" name="tropa1">
        <option value="rec_b_unit">Case1</option>
        ....
        <option value="rec_z_unit">Case20</option>
    </select>
    <input id="go" type="button">
</form>
```

Now script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#go").click(function() {

        // Obtener la referencia a las listas
        var lista1 = eval(document.getElementById("tropa1"));
        // Obtener el valor de la opción seleccionada
        var valort1 = eval(lista1.options[lista1.selectedIndex].value);
        var cadena = String(valort1);
        console.log("PHP: " + String(valort1));
        if (cadena.indexOf('z') != -1) {
            // value selected in options does not contain 'z'
            console.log("DOES NOT CONTAIN Z");
            console.log(cadena);

            confront(nu1, valort1, nu2, valort2)

        } else {
            //// value selected in options contains 'z'
            console.log("CONTAINS Z");
            console.log(cadena);
        }
    })

});
```

I tried to make this, but console return : [object Object] and not show string.
even using String() function or eval() to convert object to a string

Comment: Why do you think `eval` would convert an object to a string?

Comment: You don't need all those `eval` statements. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Since you're using JQuery, you may want to investigate JQuery's `serialize` method.  https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: var yourObject = {"name" : "stack","id":"123"};
JSON.stringify(yourObject);

@Raphael

Comment: Have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/39248551#39248551

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the content of your object in the console, you can use `console.dir()`.

If you want a function which returns a string you can override the toString() function.